# Magento 2 default Rest API not working?

Tags: magento2, checkout, rest-api

I am working on a default Magento setup and facing the default rest API not responding on checkout and throwing **401 error**.

```
{"message":"Consumer is not authorized to access %resources"...}
```

For example below APIs not working for logged in users.

```
/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/estimate-shipping-methods
/rest/default/V1/carts/309215/estimate-shipping-methods-by-address-id
/rest/V1/wishlist
```

is there any missing configuration?

is there any session/cookies related issue?

is they are customer specific?

Please share your thoughts on the same.

Answer (score 0):

To access default APi with **/mine/** you need to pass a bearer token that you generate for a customer using

> /rest/V1/integration/customer/token

with body

```
{
  "username": "test@test.com",
  "password": "admin@123"
}
```

you will get token in response , pass that in header or in authorization tab in you postman
like [image]

and for some requests you may require admin level access (you can check in ACL of that API request) , you can create admin token using

> /rest/default/V1/integration/admin/token

with body

```
{
  "username": "admin",
  "password": "admin123"
}
```

also you can refer to the [documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-token.html)

Comment: I am not creating any API, just facing these issues on default checkout process.

Comment: i am referring to existing API only